# Detectar texto dentro de um carácter especial e converte-lo em uma função PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

É possível percorrer um **textarea** para detectar um **texto** dentro do carácter **[texto]** e **transformá-lo em uma função PHP?**

### Resumindo:

**1.** Percorrer um textarea

**2.** Encontrar um texto contendo ao redor []

**3.** Converte-lo em uma função php

**4.** Exemplo: [texto] =  **Abrephp** texto(); **Fechaphp**

### Na prática:

```
 ...

  <textarea>Lorem impsun [galeria] Lorem impsun</textarea>

 ....

 //Então ao ler a informação "Lorem impsun [galeria] Lorem impsun"
 //O escopo irá tratar como(não dinamicamente):

 ...

 <div>Lorem impsun <?php galeria(); ?> Lorem impsun<div>
```

Comment: Você quer que ao detectar um conteúdo dentro de uma tag executar o comando?

Comment: Exatamente. Editado.

Comment: Faça o teste de usar jQuery `$('textarea').html().replace('[galeria]', '<b>teste</b>')` e muito facilidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o exemplo que deu:

```
function galeria() {
    return 'Funcao galeria';
}
preg_match('/<textarea>(.*?)<\/textarea>/', '<textarea>Lorem impsun [galeria] Lorem impsun</textarea>', $matches1);
$funcPattern = '/\[(.*?)\]/';
preg_match($funcPattern, $matches1[1], $matches2);
if(isset($matches2[1])) {
    if(function_exists($matches2[1])) {
        echo preg_replace($funcPattern, $matches2[1](), $matches1[1]);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Função ' .$matches2[1]. '() não existe';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'não há função definida';
}
```

Comment: tem um problema...onde está o Lorem impsun? Só me retorna "Funcao galeria". Tem que retornar: **Lorem impsun Funcao galeria Lorem impsun**

Comment: Pensei que só quisesse o que estiver dentro de `[]` @Lollipop

Comment: Não manin :( pode ajudar? Mas já dei +1 pelo preg_match

Comment: Vou editar @Lollipop

Comment: Ediatdo @Lollipop

Comment: Te amo...........

Comment: haha @Lollipop . Ainda bem que ajudei

Comment: Ficou bacana o código, só uma coisa, por que você usa o `/\[(.*?)\]/` duas vezes? +1

Comment: Obagdo é porque é suposto imprimir o que está dentro da `<textarea>` e substituir os `[...]` pelo retorno da função @zekk. Também só soube disso depois do AP dizer no 1º comentário. Vi a sua resposta, também daria com str_replace depois ... Mas não se esqueça que as funções podem ser mais do que uma. Pode haver `galeria1`, `galeria2` etc... Isso seriam muitas verificações e o codigo ficava extenso. O ultimo é para fazer replace no sitio do texto onde está o nome da função

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer... Criei uma var para a pattern @zekk. Obgado pelo reparo

Comment: Miguel, cria um novo, abaixo do que já fez, retirando um preg_match, no caso preciso que retire a condição para que NÃO seja mais entre um <textarea>, mas sim que ele detecte em qualquer local entre [texto]

Comment: Ou seja qualquer `[...]` certo de um texto qualquer @Lollipop

Comment: Isso. Imagina um monte de paragrafo e entre ele existe um [func] que chama algo. Esquece o <textarea>, mas mantem o codigo acima que ta show. É a mesma ideia só vai tirar a condição que limita entre o textarea

Comment: O motivo é porque as outras tag estão atrapalhando a execução da verificação e está dando erro.

Comment: Uma pergunta: pode haver mais do uma `[func]`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43432/discussion-between-miguel-and-lollipop).

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar a [função `strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) para verificar se uma *string* é encontrada em um texto.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <textarea name="texto" rows="4" cols="40">Lorem impsun [galeria] Lorem impsun</textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

$valorTextarea = isset($_POST['texto']) ? $_POST['texto'] : "";

if (strpos($valorTextarea, "[galeria]") !== false){
    FuncaoGaleria();
} else {
    echo "Palavra-chave não encontrada!\n";
}

function FuncaoGaleria(){
    echo "Função Galeria!\n";
}

?>
```

### Edição

Para extrair mais de uma palavra-chave do texto, use a seguinte função:

```
function extrairPalavras($texto, $sepInicial, $sepFinal){
    $resultado = [];
    $contador = $inicio = $final = 0;

    while ($contador < strlen($texto)){
        $posIn = strpos($texto, $sepInicial, $inicio);
        $posFn = strpos($texto, $sepFinal, $final);

        if ($posIn !== false){
            $inicio = $posIn + 1;

            if ($posFn !== false){
                $final = $posFn + 1;
                $resultado[$inicio] = $final;
            }
        }
        $contador++;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Use assim:

```
function funcao1() {
    return '<Funcao galeria 1>';
}
function funcao2() {
    return '<Funcao galeria 2>';
}

$texto = "Lorem [funcao2] impsun [funcao1] Lorem [heya] impsun";
$indices = extrairPalavras($texto, '[', ']');

foreach($indices as $inicial => $final){
    $nomeFunc = substr($texto, $inicial, $final - $inicial - 1);

    if(function_exists($nomeFunc)) {
        if (!isset($textoResultado)){
            $textoResultado = str_replace("[$nomeFunc]", $nomeFunc(), $texto);
            continue;
        }
        $textoResultado = str_replace("[$nomeFunc]", $nomeFunc(), $textoResultado);  
    }
}
echo $textoResultado . "\n";
// Lorem <Funcao galeria 2> impsun <Funcao galeria 1> Lorem [heya] impsun
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/VFPWWK)

Comment: E o Lorem impsun? Porque não aparece?

Comment: @Lollipop Veja a edição.

Comment: lol. perfeito..

Answer (score 1):

A pedido do @Lollipop não editei/retirei a minha primeira resposta, e ponho aqui uma solução alternativa que concluimos (por conversa em comentários/chat) que seria melhor:

```
function galeria1() {
    return htmlentities('<Funcao galeria 1>');
}
function galeria2() {
    return htmlentities('<Funcao galeria 2>');
}
$texto = 'Lorem [galeria2] impsun [galeria1] Lorem [heya] impsun';
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $texto, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $func) {
    if(function_exists($func)) {
        if(!isset($final)) {
            $final = str_replace('[' .$func. ']', $func(), $texto);
            continue;
        }
        $final = str_replace('[' .$func. ']', $func(), $final);
    }
}
echo $final;
```

Caso exista uma função não declarada dentro de `[...]` essa permanecerá no texto, caso não queira no texto acrescente o `else {...`:

```
...
if(function_exists($func)) {
    ...
}
else {
    $final = str_replace('[' .$func. ']', '', $final);
}
...
```

Comment: PERFEITO. Sem mais comentários.